# Matlab changing fontsize of axis tick

Tags: matlab, plot, font-size

I'm using Matlab to plot. I meet with errors when trying to change the fontsize of axis tick. My version is Matlab R2014a.
My toy code is as follows:

```
x = rand(1,100);
y = rand(1,100);
figure(1)
hold on
plot(x, y)
set(gca,'FontSize',18)
```

I got the error saying "Error using handle.handle/set, invalid or deleted object". I'm confused because I found many solutions on Internet and they all told me that I should use "set(gca,'FontSize',18)". But it failed.
How can I change the fontsize of axis tick?
Thank you all for helping me!!!

Comment: Works for me. Have you closed the plot?

Answer (score 1):

One potential solution is to *explicitly* use the handle to your `axes` rather than relying on `gca` to return the correct result.

```
x = rand(1,100);
y = rand(1,100);

f = figure();
hax = axes('Parent', f);
plot(x,y, 'Parent', hax)
set(hax, 'FontSize', 18)
```